# Getting error : invalid conversion from 'int' to 'std::ios_base::openmode'

Tags: c++, netbeans, int

I can't figure out why this isn't allowing me to save properly in NetBeans. It works perfectly fine in visual studios.

````
void scores(int x, Player users[])
{
    // Declarations
    fstream inScores;
    string line;
    string userName;
    int score;
    bool found = false;

    userName = users[x].userName;
    score = users[x].score;
        ```
    inScores.open("Scores.dat", ios::in | ios::out | ios::beg); 
        ``` 
    while (getline(inScores, line) && !found) {
        if (line.compare(userName) == 0) { //match strings exactly!
            found = true; // found is true => break loop
            inScores << score;
        }
    }
    inScores.close();
}
````

I expect the program to compile like it does in visual studios, however I have no idea why the same exact code doesn't compile in netbeans.

Comment: Which compiler and version is netbeans using?

Comment: You did not state which line is giving the compiler error.  Second, if I took the code you posted and attempted to compile it in Visual Studio, there would be a ton of errors.  Errors such as missing header files, the `...` you have, etc.  You could have easily written a 3 or 4 line [mcve] that duplicates the error.

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
inScores.open("Scores.dat", ios::in | ios::out | ios::beg);
```

`ios::beg` is not a valid flag to pass into fstream::open

See [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open) page for valid flags.